# How to verify ThreadPool execute method which takes Lambda as parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am currently testing a method in which I execute a runnable into a ThreadPool.

Here is the code for the method.

```
@Override
public void queueLogin(Connection connection, LoginPacket packet) {
    if(isRunning)
        loginPool.execute(() -> loginService.tryLogin(connection, packet));
}
```

Now I need to verify whether the execute method was invoked or not with the correct parameters.

Here is my test case

```
@Test
public void theQueueLoginShouldCallExecuteOnThreadPoolIfManagerIsRunning() {
    //Arrange
    loginManager.start();

    //Act
    loginManager.queueLogin(moqConnection, moqLoginPacket);

    //Assert
    verify(moqLoginPool).execute(() -> moqLoginService.tryLogin(moqConnection, moqLoginPacket));
}
```

But the test is failing saying

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
executorService.execute(
    com.battletanks.game.server.unittests.manager.login.LoginManagerTests$$Lambda$2/1668016508@3d51f06e
);
-> at com.battletanks.game.server.unittests.manager.login.LoginManagerTests.theQueueLoginShouldCallExecuteOnThreadPoolIfManagerIsNotRunning(LoginManagerTests.java:84)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
executorService.execute(
    com.battletanks.game.server.manager.login.DefaultLoginManager$$Lambda$1/77269878@7ed7259e
);
```

I understand what is wrong here but I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have it, you're relying on these two lambdas to be equal to one another. Because they don't have an overridden `equals` method, and are not the same instance, you won't be able to verify that way.

Instead, [*capture* the argument](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html), run it, and see that it does what you want it to do.

```
ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> runnableCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.for(Runnable.class);
verify(moqLoginPool).execute(runnableCaptor.capture());

verify(moqLoginService, never()).tryLogin(any(), any());
runnableCaptor.getValue().run();
verify(moqLoginService).tryLogin(any(), any());
```

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I wanted. I didn't know about ArguementCaptor. Thanks for sharing the knowledge :D

Answer (score 0):

How about verifying that moqLoginPool).execute() is called with any arguments, then make sure that after execution is finished moqLoginService.tryLogin() is called with moqConnection, moqLoginPacket?

Comment: Nope actually It won't work since I am executing a task on the thread pool and since it is a mock the tryLogin will not be executed.